# Bad request 400 in Odoo contact form. Session expired('Invalid CSRF token')

Tags: forms, csrf, odoo-10

I am facing an error in Odoo v 10 with the contact form, when I press the send button it gives an exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 195, in _dispatch
>       result = request.dispatch()
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 823, in dispatch
>       raise werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest('Session expired (invalid CSRF token)')
>   BadRequest: 400: Bad Request

If I add the code to load the CSRF token suggested in an issue of their [Github](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/10139) to the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="request.csrf_token()"/>
```

It leads me to a new blank page showing the word `false`.

In the "Web layout" I have the next javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var odoo = {
        csrf_token: "<t t-esc="request.csrf_token(None)"/>",
    };
</script>
```

I don't know if this code was manually added or it came with Odoo by default because this is an inherited installation.

The "Contact us" block is configured with the `Send an Email` action and a valid `Recipient email`, the `Thank You Page` works.

This is the final code after adding the block (without the CSRF hidden input):

```
<section class="as-contact-us" style="background-image: url(/theme_laze/static/src/img/our-work.jpg)">
    <div class="container">
        ... Company description elements ...
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <form action="/website_form/crm.lead" method="post" data-model_name="mail.mail" data-success_page="/page/website_crm.contactus_thanks" class="s_website_form form-horizontal container-fluid mt32" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="ascu-form">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input class="form-control o_website_form_input" name="contact_name" required="" placeholder="Your Name*" type="text"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input class="form-control o_website_form_input" name="email_from" required="" placeholder="Your Email*" type="text"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <textarea class="form-control o_website_form_input" name="description" required="" placeholder="Message*"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="request.csrf_token()"/>
                                <button class="creative-btn1 o_default_snippet_text">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input class="form-field" name="email_to" value="to@email.org" type="hidden"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        ... Div closures ...                    
    </div>
</section>
```

Does somebody know where is the problem?

I wouldn't like to deactivate the CSRF protection.

Answer (score 0):

I'ts a routing issue! See code below for "csrf=False" and insert to solve question.

```
# /project/admin/post/{menu.name}/{submenu.name}/insert   
@http.route(['/project/admin/post/<string:project>/<string:area>/insert'],type='http', auth='user', ***csrf=False***, website=True)
```

Comment: This answer is wrong because it shows how to disable csrf token validation instead of fixing the actual issue of having an invalid token.

Comment: I don't think is a bad answer because perhaps you need to solve the issue in relation to developing (using a controller for a custom web service)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue just enable the cookies in chrome it resolved my issue.

**Enable cookies using**.

1. Click on chrome Setting 
   [image]
2. Click Advance>> privacy and security 
   [image]
3. Click on Site Setting
   [image]
4. Click Cookies and Site Data 
   [image]
5. Enable given.
   [image]